# WCF - Error Trying to Receiving Large List of Data (~5000 objects)

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

I am attempting to transfer around 7000-8000 objects that are not large (only 9 properties per object instance). Does anyone know why when I begin to retrieve more than 5000 or so objects that I get connection errors? It works perfectly until I hit some threshold for data size.

I am exposing the retrieval of these objects via WCF's TCP service binding. I have the following sample configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBindingConfig"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <transport/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
           name="TestService">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="netTcpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfig"
              contract="ServiceInterfaces.ITestService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexTcpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8526/TestService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Services.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

From my .NET code I am calling the service using a ChannelFactory with the following sample code:

```
using (ChannelFactory<ITestervice> channel = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(BindingConfig, "net.tcp://localhost:8526/TestService"))
{
    ITestService testService = channel.CreateChannel();
    toReturn = testService.LoadAll();
    channel.Close();
}
```

BindingConfig object is a NetTcpBinding property in my code that is populated as 'new NetTcpBinding("NetTcpBindingConfig")'. My client binding is the exact same as my WCF TCP service binding.

Can anyone offer any insight as to how I can retrieve all of the data (it seems my maximum limit is ~5000 objects with my current setup)? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:
In case anyone runs into this, see the accepted solution about the MaxItemsInObjectGraph. If, however, you are using ChannelFactory from the Client to consume your services, see the following code to make it work:

```
foreach (OperationDescription operation in channel.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
{
    DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dataContractBehavior = operation.Behaviors[typeof(DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior)] as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;

    if (dataContractBehavior != null)
        dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
}
```

Comment: What are the connection errors you are getting, specifically?

Comment: "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:04:59.9980000'."

Comment: That error seems to suggest you're hitting a timeout (i.e. the SendTimeout on the client), not the reader quotas at all. Does increasing the timeout help?

Comment: I increased the sendTimeout and receiveTimeout on both the Server and Client configs to "00:30:00" and I received the same error. When I began to drill down into the InnerExceptions I noticed this error: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". The error is occurring almost instantly, so I don't think it is a timeout issue, but that I am hitting some maximum payload.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider increasing MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota as well (its default value is 64k). It should be on both the server and the client side. See the sample configuration:

[image]

Comment: You sir are a genius. This is exactly what I had to do. Since I am using the ChannelFactory, see my updated posted to find out what I did to rectify this on the Client side.